# How to capture data from camera NOT using DirectShow?

Tags: c#, windows, camera, directshow

How to capture data from camera with out using DirectShow? (in C# on windows )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done it in the past using the guidance & code from:

http://weblogs.asp.net/nleghari/pages/webcam.aspx